# Remove built-in bookshelves prior to plastering

Tags: repair, walls, plaster

I'm looking for any advice as to how to go about removing a built-in bookshelf (8cm deep, 173cm tall, 26cm wide), prior to skim plastering the wall completely flat (by a professional.) The interior of the bookshelf has been previously skimmed with *modern* plaster (as opposed to the lath plaster of the surrounding wall.)

I'm completely new to plastering, and am unsure how it might dry/wear over any material(s) used to fill the bookshelf cavity. Searching online there seems to be *a lot* of information as to how to install built-in bookshelves, but nothing on filling them in (though this might be a failing of my keywords...)

So far I've considered; covering/filling the hole flush with plasterboard (but don't want the plaster to crack if the plasterboard expands/shrinks relative to the original lath plaster wall), or using expanding foam (but am concerned plaster will not stick to it.) One assumes the hole is far too large and deep to be simply filled with plaster (or am I overthinking this whole thing?)

Thanks in advance!

[image: Built-in bookshelves (8cm deep, 173cm tall, 26cm wide)]

Comment: You want to get rid of it? Or you want it prepped for plaster (and retained?)

Comment: To get rid of - will update my question now!

Comment: If you are hiring a 'pro', maybe they can take care of it for you.